# Como carregar informações de um BD para o formulário?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Olá, pessoal e boa tarde!
Vou lhes explicar meu problema e frisar que gostaria que resolvesse apenas com PHP, mas quase certeza de precisar de outra linguagem.

Eu gostaria de em um formulário, em uma tag  ter opções com nomes de empresas, por exemplo: Microsoft, Apple, Google, etc. E a partir da escolha desta empresa um formulário abaixo puxar do BD as informações e autopreencher os dados do formulário.

Poderiam me elucidar como fazer isto? Procurei pela internet e a maioria cita o jQuery para fazer tal ação, porém infelizmente não tenho conhecimento em js.

[image: No caso, ao invés de ser "Incluir nova empresa" será o nome da empresa e os outros campos serão preenchidos automaticamente.]

No caso, ao invés de ser "Incluir nova empresa" será o nome da empresa e os outros campos serão preenchidos automaticamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1º Passo:

> **Arquivo _form.php**
>
> Script

```
function loadDoc() {
   var empresa = document.getElementById('empresa').value;
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
       this.responseText;
     }
   };
     xhttp.open("GET", "_form2.php?empresa="+empresa, true);
     xhttp.send();

 }
```

HTML

```
<form>
  <select name="empresa" size="5" id="empresa">
    <option value="Microsoft">Microsoft</option>
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Google">Google</option>
  </select>

 <button type='button' onclick="loadDoc()">Submit</button>
 </form>
 <!-- na div abaixo será retornado o resultado da consulta -->
 <div id='result'>
 </div>
```

2º passo:

> Arquivo _form2.php

```
$empresa=$_GET["empresa"];
//bonus 
$empresa=mb_convert_encoding($empresa, "UTF-8");

    $link = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "DB");

    if($link->connect_errno){
         echo"Deu ruim";
         exit();
    }


        $sqli = ("SELECT empresa,razao,cnpj,tel FROM stabela WHERE empresa = '$empresa'");
        $resultado_pedido = mysqli_query($link,$sqli);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado_pedido) > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_pedido)) {
                    $empresa=$row["empresa"];
                    $razao=$row["razao"];
                    $cnpj=$row["cnpj"];
                    $tel=$row["tel"];
                }
            }

   mysqli_close($link);

   echo ("<form>");
   echo "<br>";
   echo ("<input type=\"text\" name=\"empr\" id=\"empr\" value=\"".$empresa."\">");
   echo "<br>";
   echo ("<input type=\"text\" name=\"empr\" id=\"empr\" value=\"".$razao."\">");
   echo "<br>";
   echo ("<input type=\"text\" name=\"empr\" id=\"empr\" value=\"".$cnpj."\">");
   echo "<br>";
   echo ("<input type=\"text\" name=\"empr\" id=\"empr\" value=\"".$tel."\">");
   echo ("</form>");
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Leo Caracciolo, modifiquei um pouco o código e irei postar aqui, porém como não sabia muito de javascript, facilitou na criação do código!.